# Perfect Square function that doesn't return

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm a beginner working with Python and I was given this task: *write a function which returns the highest perfect square which is less or equal to its parameter (a positive integer).*

```
def perfsq(n):

    x = 0
    xy = x * x
    if n >= 0:
        while xy < n:
            x += 1

        if xy != n:
            print (("%s is not a perfect square.") % (n))
            x -= 1
            print (("%s is the next highest perfect square.") % (xy))
        else:
            return(print(("%s is a perfect square of %s.") % (n, x)))
```

When I run the code to execute the function it doesn't output anything. I'll admit, I'm struggling and if you could give me some advice on how to fix this, I would be grateful.

Comment: Look at your `while` loop.  When will it stop looping?

Comment: Could you please post some output?

Comment: A hint unrelated to code: All perfect squares are the sums of consecutive odd integers

Comment: `return(print(...` makes little sense. Don't confuse function returns and prints.

Comment: `xy = x*x` execute once *outside* the loop won't cause `xy` to be always equal to `x*x` *inside* the loop. Python variables are not like spreadsheet cells which automatically update when other values are changed.

Comment: If you fixed the problems highlighted in the other comments then the code still wouldn't work because in your `if` statement you execute the code if `xy` does not equal `n`. In your while loop you are only executing so long as `xy` is less than `n`. Therefore the `else` statement will never be executed as xy will always not be equal to n

Comment: Nothing in the problem description requires treating the case of a perfect square differently than any other parameter value, and nothing in the problem description involves printing anything. Of course, code which *tests* your function might print the return value.

Answer (score 1):

your loop condition which is

```
while xy < n:
```

this will be true always as xy is always 0 and n is always greater then zero if you will call the function with n = 0, it will print `0 is a perfect square of 0.` and will return None.

```
for n > 0
```

why it is always `true` in the case of `xy < n` because you have assigned xy `0` and never modified it to anyother value when a loop runs it check the condition and it will always get `True`

Answer (score 0):

Like Patrick Haugh says, try examining when the while loop exits. It can be helpful to put print() statements throughout your method to figure out how your method executes. In order to figure out when your loop exits, look at the exit condition of your while loop: xy < n.

Remember, a variable isn't updated until you update it.

```
def perfsq(n):
    x = 0
    xy = x * x
    print("xy: {}".format(xy))
    if n >= 0:
        while xy < n:
            x += 1
            print("xy in loop: {}".format(xy))

        if xy != n:
            print (("%s is not a perfect square.") % (n))
            x -= 1
            print (("%s is the next highest perfect square.") % (xy))
        else:
            return(print(("%s is a perfect square of %s.") % (n, x)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I see your mistake, and it's an easy one for someone to make.  When you define

```
xy = x*x
```

the computer calculates `x*x` and assigns that *number* to be the value of `xy`. So when you then add one to `x` it does not change the value of `xy`.  You have to tell the computer to recalculate `xy` every time:

```
while xy < n:
    x += 1
    xy = x*x
```

Comment: It might be more accurate to say "I see *one* of your mistakes." Even if they fix that one bug, the resulting code will still fail to meet the function spec.

Answer (score -1):

```
def perfsq(n):

    x = 0
    xy = x * x
    if n >= 0:
        while xy < n:
            x += 1
            xy = x*x <-- Here

        if xy != n:
            print (("%s is not a perfect square.") % (n))
            x -= 1
            xy = x*x  <--Here
            print (("%s is the next highest perfect square.") % (xy))
        else:
            print(("%s is a perfect square of %s.") % (n, x)) <--And here
```

Think about that.